# Convert objects with the clamp constrain to a single mesh

Tags: modeling

So I created a circle with leafs

[image]

And I used a method from an older question here on stackexchange [Spawn planes around a circle?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7982/spawn-planes-around-a-circle)

And this is how I have done it

[image]

But now I have to rig my mesh and I get weird results with rigify. Is is possible to convert the complete circle of leafs to a real mesh?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "real mesh", but try pressing `Ctrl+A` > *Apply Visible transform* with the leaves selected and then removing the constraints.

Comment: If you need help getting the leaves to move in a particular way on your rigged character, feel free to ask another question or to revise this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Joining mesh objects**

Yes, you can use the Join command by selecting all the mesh objects you want to join together, then pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>. They should now all be one object. However, the different leaves will not be able to move separately once the character starts moving unless you convert them into cloth objects or perhaps use soft body physics.